# Animating width causes inner element to jump up from unknown height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm animating an arrow like so.

**HTML**

```
<div id="next-section" class="arrow"><p>Next Section</p></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#next-section p {
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#next-section {
  height:2em;
  width:10em;
  margin: 1.25em 0 1.25em 2em;
  line-height: 2.125em;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
#next-section.arrow {
  background-color: #fdb726;
  color:#54261a;
  height:2.15em;
}
#next-section.arrow:after, #next-section.arrow:before, #next-section.arrow.move-on:after, #next-section.arrow.move-on:before  {
  border-width: 1.063em 0 1.063em 1.063em;
}
#next-section.arrow:before {
  border-color: #fdb726 transparent;
  left: -1.063em;
  top: 0;
}
#next-section.arrow:after {
  border-color: transparent #fdb726;
  right: -1.063em;
  top: 0;
}
#next-section:before, #next-section:after   {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0;
}
#next-section.arrow.move-on, #next-section.arrow.move-on:before, #next-section.arrow.move-on:after {
  z-index:1;
}
#next-section.arrow.move-on {
  background:#54261a;
  color:white;
  right:2em;
  bottom:3.4em;
  width:0;
}
#next-section.arrow.move-on p {
  padding-bottom:1.25em;
}
#next-section.arrow.move-on:before {
  border-color:#54261a transparent;
}
#next-section.arrow.move-on:after {
  border-color:transparent #54261a;
}
#next-section.arrow.feather:before {
  border-color:#54261a transparent;
}
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

  $.fn.arrowWipe = function() {
    var hoveredItem = $(this);
      var cloneItem = $(this)
        .clone()
        .addClass('move-on');
      hoveredItem.append(cloneItem);
  };

  $('#next-section').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $('#next-section').addClass('feather');
      $(this).arrowWipe();
      $('.move-on').animate({width:'100%'},300);
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
      $('#next-section').removeClass('feather');
      $('.move-on').remove();
    }
  });

});
```

Basically, I want people to be able to hover over the button and get an animation with a "growing" arrow of different colors that expands from left to right. My issue is that the "Next Section" text of the cloned elements starts out in the wrong position and jumps up to where it needs to be when the animation is complete.

One common fix I've found for this is supposedly setting overflow to hidden, but trying this out results in the pseudo elements disappearing. Other adjustments of margins and padding seems to have no effect.

Why is this happening and how might I fix it?

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/bathybic/pen/GqBWyQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Animate applies "overflow:hidden" while animating in order to prevent elements from escaping, so to speak. For anyone else struggling with this problem, while questionably hack-y (mostly because I hate !important and this is overriding the default... but it negates the whole collapsing thing), doing this:

```
#next-section.arrow.move-on {
background:#54261a;
color:white;
right:2em;
bottom:3.4em;
width:0;
overflow:visible !important;
}
```

...ended up rectifying the issue.